# xlrd copying cell style from xls to xlsx

Tags: xlsxwriter, xlrd

Im trying to convert xls to xlsx files including cell style. At the moment, Im working with cell fonts.
Is there another way for xlrd to determine whether the cell font is bold or not other than font._font_flag == 1?

```
def xlstoxlsx():
input_file_loc = [x for x in os.listdir(path1) if x.endswith(".xls")]
count = 0
for file in input_file_loc:
    xlsxwb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f"{path1}/" + input_file_loc[count] + '_Coverted {:2d}.xlsx'.format(count))
    xlswb = xlrd.open_workbook(path1 + "/" + file, formatting_info=True)
    bold = xlsxwb.add_format({'bold': True})
    italic = xlsxwb.add_format({'italic': True})
    uline = xlsxwb.add_format({'underline': True})
    for sht in xlswb.sheet_names():
        xlsws = xlswb[sht]
        rows, cols = xlsws.nrows, xlsws.ncols
        all_rows = []
        for row in range(rows):
            curr_row = []
            for col in range(cols):
                curr_row.append(xlsws.cell_value(row, col))
            all_rows.append(curr_row)
        xlsxws = xlsxwb.add_worksheet()
        for row in range(len(all_rows)):
            for col in range(len(all_rows[0])):
                cell = xlsws.cell(row, col)
                font = xlswb.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
                if font._font_flag == 1:
                    xlsxws.write(row, col, all_rows[row][col], bold)
                elif font._font_flag == 0:
                    xlsxws.write(row, col, all_rows[row][col])
    count += 1
    xlsxwb.close()
```